# build my own function that does the same work as 'semilogx' MATLAB function

Tags: matlab

How can I build my own function in Matlab that does the same work as the Matlab built-in function 'semilogx'?

Example:  in this example both fig.1 and fig.2 plot x as a log scale but the values on the x-axis of fig.1 are not correct. So the question is "how can I make the values in fig.1 same as the values in fig.2 without using semilogx?"

```
x = 0:1000;

y = 2*x;

figure(1), plot(log10(x), y) 

figure(2), semilogx(x,y)
```

I guess in my example above: in Fig.1 x limit is between [0,3] and in Fig.2 x limit is between [0,1000]. What I understand is that x limit should be [0:1000] but when we use log scale this would change to [0,3] so the semilogx function only maps the [0,3] limit to [0,1000]

Comment: Why don't you want to use `semilogx`?

Comment: Why not ask someone to write it for you in Swift instead of in MATLAB? (Although in both cases requests for novel code are off-topic for Stack Overflow so this might not be the place to make this particular request)

Comment: You need to write the value of `x(i)` at location `log10(x(i))` on the x-axis. But showing you how to do this in MATLAB is irrelevant if you want to do this in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to reconstruct the x-axis tick mark locations and the corresponding tick labels on a log-scaled grid:

```
% Some data
x = 1:1000;
y = cumsum(rand(size(x)));

% For comparison
subplot(311); plot(log10(x), y)
subplot(312); semilogx(x,y)

% Simulated semilogx plot
subplot(313); plot(log10(x), y)
ax = gca; % Get a handle to the axis for tick modifications

% Compute tick mark locations in log10 scale
logxmax = ceil(log10(x(end)));
ticks = log10(1:9);
ticks = ticks' + (0:logxmax-1);
ticks = [ticks(:); logxmax];

% Set tick marks and labels
ax.XTick = ticks;
ax.XLim = [0 logxmax];

% Reset tick labels
ax.XTickLabel(:) = ''; % clear all tick labels
I = 1+9*(0:logxmax); % Tick labels for 10^n locations
S = arrayfun(@(x)'10^{'+string(x)+'}', (0:logxmax), 'UniformOutput', false);
ax.XTickLabel(I) = S;
```

[image]